# Is there anyway to edit js code in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, router, inspect-element

I have been trying to bypass my 3g modem's login page since I forgot my password. I used inspect element from chrome and I got a piece of code that accepts the validity of the username and password from an unkown method. It uses the if else method. I am trying to edit the js code but the changes are not reflected or are simply not made.
For those who may think I am trying to access someone else's network illegally,
I hereby declare that I **do** own the modem and I will not use the methods given by the users for illegal purposes.
Any help is appreciated.
Thankyou.

Comment: You best just put a breakpoint and edit the content of whatever is being checked. You cannot "save" changes you've made to JS in the browser, unless you have access to the files.

Comment: You are not going to bypass it.... reset the router.

Comment: You can't break the authentication of the modem on the login page. Why not just return the default settings?

Comment: There is no reset button on the modem. It is a usb modem. And there is no option to reset to default. Some freak just changed my password

Comment: Now look, there's nothing you can do on that login page to circumvent the actual login. As you can see, your credentials are send to an internal app of the modem, and if that won't get the correct credentials, you're blocked out on all app pages.

Comment: I have included the code. I just want the changes in the code to be applied in the script

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome, in the source tab of the developer tools, you can click the Filesystem "subtab" which allows to override remote scripts with local ones:

[image]

Not sure if this will allow you to hack anything like router's authentication since the entry point is the HTTP endpoint, not the web page.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it please.